# Pandas comparison

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to simplify pandas and python syntax when executing a basic Pandas operation.

I have 4 columns:

- a_id
- a_score
- b_id
- b_score

I create a new label called **doc_type** based on the following:

- a >= b, **doc_type**: a
- b > a,  **doc_type**: b

Im struggling in how to calculate in Pandas where a exists but b doesn't, in this case then a needs to be the label. Right now it returns the else statement or b.
I needed to create 2 additional comparison which at scale may be efficient as I already compare the data before. Looking how to improve it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'a_id': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '', 'F', 'G'],
        'a_score': [1, 2, 3, 4, '', 6, 7],
        'b_id': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', ''],
        'b_score': [0.1, 0.2, 3.1, 4.1, 5, 5.99, None],

    })
    print df
    # Replace empty string with NaN
    m_score = r['a_score'] >= r['b_score']
    m_doc = (r['a_id'].isnull() & r['b_id'].isnull())
    df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x).replace('', np.nan)
    # Calculate higher score
    df['doc_id'] = df.apply(lambda df: df['a_id'] if df['a_score'] >= df['b_score'] else df['b_id'], axis=1)
    # Select type based on higher score
    r['doc_type'] = numpy.where(m_score, 'a',
                          numpy.where(m_doc, numpy.nan, 'b'))      

    # Additional lines looking for improvement:
    df['doc_type'].loc[(df['a_id'].isnull() & df['b_id'].notnull())] = 'b'
    df['doc_type'].loc[(df['a_id'].notnull() & df['b_id'].isnull())] = 'a'
    print df
```

Comment: Do you need the doc_id in reality? or it's just part of your processing code?

Comment: Is just part of the processing code, we can ignore it for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numpy.where`, assuming your logic is:

- Both exist, the doc_type will be the one with higher score;
- One missing, the doc_type will be the one not null;
- Both missing, the doc_type will be null;

Added an extra edge case at the last line:

```
import numpy as np

df = df.replace('', np.nan)
df['doc_type'] = np.where(df.b_id.isnull() | (df.a_score >= df.b_score), 
                          np.where(df.a_id.isnull(), None, 'a'), 'b')
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the apply method in pandas with a custom function, trying out on your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'a_id': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '', 'F', 'G'],
        'a_score': [1, 2, 3, 4, '', 6, 7],
        'b_id': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', ''],
        'b_score': [0.1, 0.2, 3.1, 4.1, 5, 5.99, None],

    })

df = df.replace('',np.NaN)

def func(row):
    if np.isnan(row.a_score) and np.isnan(row.b_score):
        return np.NaN
    elif np.isnan(row.b_score) and not(np.isnan(row.a_score)):
        return 'a'
    elif not(np.isnan(row.b_score)) and np.isnan(row.a_score):
        return 'a'
    elif row.a_score>=row.b_score:
        return 'a'
    elif row.b_score>row.a_score:
        return 'b'

df['doc_type'] = df.apply(func,axis=1)
```

You can make the function as complicated as you need and include any amount of comparisons and add more conditions later if you need to.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, for row 7 (index 6) your logic doesn't work, it returns None, it should return 'a' as there is a value for a_id and a_score. Is the same problem Im describing above.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand all conditions or if this has any particular edge cases, but I think you can just do an `np.argmax` on the columns and swap the values for 'a' or 'b' when you're done:

```
In [21]: import numpy as np

In [22]: df['doc_type'] = pd.Series(np.argmax(df[["a_score", "b_score"]].values, axis=1)).replace({0: 'a', 1: 'b'})

In [23]: df
Out[23]:
  a_id a_score b_id  b_score doc_type
0    A       1    a     0.10        a
1    B       2    b     0.20        a
2    C       3    c     3.10        b
3    D       4    d     4.10        b
4            2    e     5.00        b
5    F            f     5.99        a
6    G       7           NaN        a
```